# How to add rt patches in linux

Tags: linux, patch

I want to add rt patches to Linux, i took 3.18.9 kernel and 3.18.9-rt4 patch. 
    i copied patches-3.18.9-rt4.tar.gz into Linux kernel folder. 
    Now I executed 
    zcat patches-3.18.9-rt4.tar.gz | patch -p1
    After executing this command it is asking for file to patch as shown below

```
|--- a/arch/sparc/Kconfig
|+++ b/arch/sparc/Kconfig
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

I want to add all patches in one go, How can I achieve this ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this should go to http://superuser.com/ -- it's not a programming issue. Add info from what directory you're executing the `patch` command, looks like the `-p` option doesn't match here.

Answer (score 6):

**The problem**

The patch you are using contains the RT patch as a large number of separate files, bundled up into a `tar` archive, then compressed into a `gz` file. Running `zcat` (or friends) on the file will uncompress it, then pass the result to `patch`.

However, since the result after uncompressing your patch file is a `.tar` archive, this is also what is passed into `patch`, which isn't going to work.

**The easy solution**

Use the single-file version of the RT patch instead, which is just a compressed `.patch` file (these versions can be recognized by being called "patch-..." instead of "patches-...", 3.18.9-rt5 can be downloaded from here: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/3.18/older/patch-3.18.9-rt5.patch.gz).

Then follow the instructions from the [RT Preempt Howto](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RT_PREEMPT_HOWTO): (just adjust it to your own kernel version / compression format)

> **Patching the Kernel**
>
> After downloading, unpack the kernel tarball and change into the kernel source directory. Patch the kernel with patch level p1:
>
> ```
> tar xfj linux-2.6.23.1.tar.bz2 
> cd linux-2.6.23.1
> bzcat ../patch-2.6.23.1-rt11.bz2 | patch -p1
> ```

Comment: Ah, missed the `.tar.gz` first looking at this. Maybe add *why* it isn't working: `.tar` is an archive of multiple files and `zcat`/`bzcat`/... are just for uncompressing one single file.